# MySQL update playlist query possible?

Tags: php, mysql, playlist

```
playlist
+----+----------+---------------+
| id | uploader | name          |
+----+----------+---------------+
|  1 |        1 | Testplaylist1 |
|  2 |        1 | ...           |
+----+----------+---------------+ 

playlistvideo
| id | plid | videoid | videopos |
+----+------+---------+----------+
|  1 |    1 |       1 |        1 |
|  2 |    1 |       2 |        2 |
|  3 |    1 |       3 |        3 |
|  4 |    1 |       4 |        4 |
|  5 |    1 |       5 |        5 |
|  6 |    1 |       6 |        6 |
|  7 |    2 |     ... |      ... |
+----+------+---------+----------+
```

I have these two tables (among others) and **I'm trying to update the position of the videos** in the *playlistvideo* table. I need to follow these "conditions/constraints":

- The new video position `videopos` is a variable `$newPos` between 1 and 6, let's say 2.
- The video id `videoid` to be "moved" to the new position, 2, is the video id belonging to another `videopos` variable `$oldPos` , let's say position 1.
- the playlist id `playlistvideo.plid` must belong to a specific uploader in `playlist.uploader`, in this case uploader 1.
- So video id 1 gets position 2, we dont have to mind video id 2's position being the same, I'm repeating the process for all of them.

So that means I'll step by step run through all of the `videoid : videopos`from position 1 to N in all of uploader 1's playlists every time a change has happened.

Here's a sample data of what I can work with, where in the first playlist, video position 2 has been moved to video position 1. You can see the positions restarting a bit down, this means we're in the 2nd playlist and no moving has occured. This is from an array, where the array-indexes (`$newPos`) acts as the video-positions in each playlist.

```
newPos: 1 oldPos: 2
newPos: 2 oldPos: 1
newPos: 3 oldPos: 3
newPos: 4 oldPos: 4
newPos: 5 oldPos: 5
newPos: 6 oldPos: 6
newPos: 1 oldPos: 1
newPos: 2 oldPos: 2
newPos: 3 oldPos: 3
newPos: 4 oldPos: 4
```

Can a MySQL query manage this or do I need more data?

Comment: This isn't going to work if all you know is `$oldPos` and `$newPos`. After you move 2 to 1, you'll have two videos with position 1. Then when you move 1 to 2, it will move both of them.

Comment: Everything's 1. That's no fun.

Comment: much (much) simpler to just rearrange the arrays in php then save each row with their new order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following

```
if ($newPos > $oldPos)
{
    $query = "UPDATE playlistvideo SET videopos = IF(videopos = $oldPos, $newPos, videopos -1) WHERE videopos >= $oldPos AND videopos <= $newPos";
}
else if ($newPos < $oldPos)
{
    $query = "UPDATE playlistvideo SET videopos = IF(videopos = $oldPos, $newPos, videopos +1) WHERE videopos >= $newPos AND videopos <= $oldPos";
}
```

To do it entirely in SQL it would be

```
UPDATE playlistvideo 
SET videopos = IF(videopos = $oldPos, $newPos, videopos + IF($oldPos > $newPos,1,IF($oldPos = $newPos, 0, -1)))
WHERE videopos BETWEEN $newPos AND $oldPos
```

Comment: Yes! This is great, it almost went through perfectly with what I have. I can work it out with this. Thank you!